# Internal Server Error 500 after exactly 4 postbacks

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajax, vb.net

Writing a web application in ASP.NET/VB.NET (Framework Version 4.0), I am facing a strange problem. After exactly 4 **successful** partial postbacks using any of buttons on page (static, dynamic or any combination of these), I get the following errors on every further button click (Google Chrome Console Output):

```
POST http://localhost:88/DataEntry/EditBrands.aspx 500 (Internal Server Error) ScriptResource.axd?d=vwQCAnS4Sdynl0YttgGBrSVuxnFroO9N1g-wQUB-ZdYbpgtVUIyZOF4iFfT65Up7mAVfbXPLwwYvzQ…:6076
Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 500 ScriptResource.axd?d=vwQCAnS4Sdynl0YttgGBrSVuxnFroO9N1g-wQUB-ZdYbpgtVUIyZOF4iFfT65Up7mAVfbXPLwwYvzQ…:237
POST http://localhost:88/DataEntry/EditBrands.aspx 500 (Internal Server Error) ScriptResource.axd?d=vwQCAnS4Sdynl0YttgGBrSVuxnFroO9N1g-wQUB-ZdYbpgtVUIyZOF4iFfT65Up7mAVfbXPLwwYvzQ…:6076
Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 500 ScriptResource.axd?d=vwQCAnS4Sdynl0YttgGBrSVuxnFroO9N1g-wQUB-ZdYbpgtVUIyZOF4iFfT65Up7mAVfbXPLwwYvzQ…:237
Error$create ScriptResource.axd?d=vwQCAnS4Sdynl0YttgGBrSVuxnFroO9N1g-wQUB-ZdYbpgtVUIyZOF4iFfT65Up7mAVfbXPLwwYvzQ…:237
Sys$WebForms$PageRequestManager$_createPageRequestManagerServerError ScriptResource.axd?d=DmtLNNhZ6S2WBV3HC3HiOZllqg2PWJeQH42XaiDWtnvfM09lT2a1nwl_mdhJA2QZRpjyz1XIk9V_Uv…:656
Sys$WebForms$PageRequestManager$_onFormSubmitCompleted ScriptResource.axd?d=DmtLNNhZ6S2WBV3HC3HiOZllqg2PWJeQH42XaiDWtnvfM09lT2a1nwl_mdhJA2QZRpjyz1XIk9V_Uv…:1311
(anonymous function) ScriptResource.axd?d=vwQCAnS4Sdynl0YttgGBrSVuxnFroO9N1g-wQUB-ZdYbpgtVUIyZOF4iFfT65Up7mAVfbXPLwwYvzQ…:47
(anonymous function) ScriptResource.axd?d=vwQCAnS4Sdynl0YttgGBrSVuxnFroO9N1g-wQUB-ZdYbpgtVUIyZOF4iFfT65Up7mAVfbXPLwwYvzQ…:3484
Sys$Net$WebRequest$completed ScriptResource.axd?d=vwQCAnS4Sdynl0YttgGBrSVuxnFroO9N1g-wQUB-ZdYbpgtVUIyZOF4iFfT65Up7mAVfbXPLwwYvzQ…:6376
Sys$Net$XMLHttpExecutor._onReadyStateChange ScriptResource.axd?d=vwQCAnS4Sdynl0YttgGBrSVuxnFroO9N1g-wQUB-ZdYbpgtVUIyZOF4iFfT65Up7mAVfbXPLwwYvzQ…:5996
POST http://localhost:88/DataEntry/EditBrands.aspx 500 (Internal Server Error) ScriptResource.axd?d=vwQCAnS4Sdynl0YttgGBrSVuxnFroO9N1g-wQUB-ZdYbpgtVUIyZOF4iFfT65Up7mAVfbXPLwwYvzQ…:6076
Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 500 ScriptResource.axd?d=vwQCAnS4Sdynl0YttgGBrSVuxnFroO9N1g-wQUB-ZdYbpgtVUIyZOF4iFfT65Up7mAVfbXPLwwYvzQ…:237
POST http://localhost:88/DataEntry/EditBrands.aspx 500 (Internal Server Error) ScriptResource.axd?d=vwQCAnS4Sdynl0YttgGBrSVuxnFroO9N1g-wQUB-ZdYbpgtVUIyZOF4iFfT65Up7mAVfbXPLwwYvzQ…:6076
Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 500 ScriptResource.axd?d=vwQCAnS4Sdynl0YttgGBrSVuxnFroO9N1g-wQUB-ZdYbpgtVUIyZOF4iFfT65Up7mAVfbXPLwwYvzQ…:237
POST http://localhost:88/DataEntry/EditBrands.aspx 500 (Internal Server Error) ScriptResource.axd?d=vwQCAnS4Sdynl0YttgGBrSVuxnFroO9N1g-wQUB-ZdYbpgtVUIyZOF4iFfT65Up7mAVfbXPLwwYvzQ…:6076
Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 500 ScriptResource.axd?d=vwQCAnS4Sdynl0YttgGBrSVuxnFroO9N1g-wQUB-ZdYbpgtVUIyZOF4iFfT65Up7mAVfbXPLwwYvzQ…:237
```

Paddling with web.config and adding or removing any lines suggested in many posts (including posts in stackoverflow) doesn't help. I am not using any non-.Net Framework methods, custom JavaScript or anything else outside Microsoft AJAX. This happens in both ASP.NET Development Server coming with VS 2010 and IIS 7.5 on Windows 7. I have no other option(s) to test this app on, but believe that this isn't coming from server/OS. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention that only the first error is expanded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't believe it, but the problem was the DATA in the database! I looked at event viewer and found this record on every error:

```
Event code: 3003 
Event message: A validation error has occurred. 
Event time: 8/20/2014 8:23:23 AM 
Event time (UTC): 8/20/2014 3:53:23 AM 
Event ID: b7431169717242c2b17b76aa2bd095a1 
Event sequence: 36 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: 9b91b513-62-130529186126183869 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: E:\Projects\PharmaManage\PharmaManage Web\ 
    Machine name: MOHAMMAD-PC 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 7188 
    Process name: WebDev.WebServer40.exe 
    Account name: Mohammad-PC\Mohammad 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: HttpRequestValidationException 
    Exception message: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00$PageContent$AddGName="...S+GINSENG <SEVEN SEAS> PEARL").
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateString(String value, String collectionKey, RequestValidationSource requestCollection)
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateHttpValueCollection(HttpValueCollection collection, RequestValidationSource requestCollection)
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form()
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_HasForm()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.GetCollectionBasedOnMethod(Boolean dontReturnNull)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.DeterminePostBackMode()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at ASP.dataentry_editbrands_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)



Request information: 
    Request URL: http://localhost:54756/DataEntry/EditBrands.aspx 
    Request path: /DataEntry/EditBrands.aspx 
    User host address: 127.0.0.1 
    User: Mohammad-PC\Mohammad 
    Is authenticated: True 
    Authentication Type: NTLM 
    Thread account name: Mohammad-PC\Mohammad 

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 140 
    Thread account name: Mohammad-PC\Mohammad 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateString(String value, String collectionKey, RequestValidationSource requestCollection)
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateHttpValueCollection(HttpValueCollection collection, RequestValidationSource requestCollection)
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form()
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_HasForm()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.GetCollectionBasedOnMethod(Boolean dontReturnNull)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.DeterminePostBackMode()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at ASP.dataentry_editbrands_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)


Custom event details:
```

Source of error is explicitly visible in Exception Information section. Some records contained "<" and ">" characters which caused validation failures. Because these were considered as HTML tags, I couldn't see them and so couldn't find source of the problem prior to event viewer check. I solved it simply by replacing all "<" and ">" with other characters, say "(" and ")" respectively.

Regards